# Print the nth step of a Generator in an easy way

Tags: python, generator

I want to know if there is a better and cleaner way of printing the 3rd step of a generator function.
Currently I have written the following code

```
def imparesgen():
  n = 0
  while n<200: 
    n=n+2
    yield n

gen = imparesgen()

y = 0
for x in gen:
  y+=1
  if y == 3:
    print(x)
```

This worked, but, is there maybe a simpler way of doing this? Without the use of a list.

Comment: Could you just store the results of the generation in an array and then refer to the index that you want? Anything preventing us from doing that? Or maybe if you need the generator, you can put the print loop in another function that you call later on?

Comment: Can you use `gen = list(imparesgen())` and then `print(gen[2])`?

Comment: @RichardKYu I dont want to store it in a list, I want it to be as efficient as I can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def nth(iterable, n, default=None):
    "Returns the nth item or a default value"
    return next(islice(iterable, n, None), default)
```

Applied to your example:

```
import itertools

def imparesgen():
  n = 0
  while n<200:
    n=n+2
    yield n

gen = imparesgen()

print(next(itertools.islice(gen, 3, None)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the generator three times. Since `zip` stops at the shortest input, you'll only get three iterations provided `gen` yields at least three elements.

```
gen = imparesgen()
for _, item in zip(range(3), gen):
    pass

# Now, item is the third element
print(item)
```

Alternatively, use the `next()` function to get the next element of the generator:

```
gen = imparesgen()
next(gen)
next(gen)
item = next(gen)
print(item)
```

Or, if you don't want to write out those `next` lines multiple times:

```
gen = imparesgen()
for _ in range(3):
    item = next(gen)

print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?:

```
from itertools import islice

def imparesgen():
  n = 0
  while n<200: 
    n=n+2
    yield n

gen = imparesgen()

third = list(islice(gen, 2, 3))[0]  # -> 6
```

Answer (score -2):

Since a generator acts like an iterator, you can call [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on it :

```py
third = next(next(next(gen)))
```

I don't think you can go much faster than that in pure-Python. But I think that without benchmarking the code, the speedup won't be noticed.

Comment: `next` returns the next element of the generator, so you can't chain them like this

Comment: Indeed. Not on a computer, so did not test. But next is the way to go.